# Unable to traverse improperly grouped data from Wikipedia API

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I'm attempting to traverse data obtained from the wikipedia API and place it into an array. The JSON which is returned by wikipedia has the following structure.

As you can see the pageid is used as a way to group the items. How can I traverse or loop through this such that I can obtain the `canonicalurl` for any given page?

## Wikipedia Returns this

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "gsroffset": 10,
        "continue": "gsroffset||"
    },
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "1649961": {
                "pageid": 1649961,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Billie",
                "index": 1,
                "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                "pagelanguage": "en",
                "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "en",
                "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
                "touched": "2021-07-20T00:17:32Z",
                "lastrevid": 1034458537,
                "length": 1849,
                "fullurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billie",
                "editurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Billie&action=edit",
                "canonicalurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billie"
            },
            "53785363": {
                "pageid": 53785363,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Billie Eilish",
                "index": 2,
                "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                "pagelanguage": "en",
                "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "en",
                "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
                "touched": "2021-07-26T23:44:36Z",
                "lastrevid": 1035658312,
                "length": 150193,
                "fullurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billie_Eilish",
                "editurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Billie_Eilish&action=edit",
                "canonicalurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billie_Eilish"
            }
}
```

## I'm trying to get this

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "gsroffset": 10,
        "continue": "gsroffset||"
    },
    "query": {
        "pages": {
              {
                "pageid": 1649961,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Billie",
                "index": 1,
                "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                "pagelanguage": "en",
                "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "en",
                "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
                "touched": "2021-07-20T00:17:32Z",
                "lastrevid": 1034458537,
                "length": 1849,
                "fullurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billie",
                "editurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Billie&action=edit",
                "canonicalurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billie"
            },
            {
                "pageid": 53785363,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Billie Eilish",
                "index": 2,
                "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                "pagelanguage": "en",
                "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "en",
                "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
                "touched": "2021-07-26T23:44:36Z",
                "lastrevid": 1035658312,
                "length": 150193,
                "fullurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billie_Eilish",
                "editurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Billie_Eilish&action=edit",
                "canonicalurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billie_Eilish"
            }
}
```

### This is how I call the API

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query&generator=search&prop=info&inprop=url&format=json&gsrsearch=',
    headers: {'Api-User-Agent':'EventGator (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080)'}
});

export const getApiSuggestions = (title) => {
    console.log(title);

    let result = url
        .get(`${title}`)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("Requests: "+response.data.query.pages); //this can't be parsed as a set of objects
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return error;
        });

    return result;
};
```

## And I map the results like this:

```
            <SuggestContainer>
                <Ul>
                    {loading && <Li>Loading...</Li>}
                    {options?.matches?.length > 0 &&
                        !loading &&
                        options.matches?.map((option) => (
                            <Li key={`${option.pageid}-${option.canonicalurl}`}
                                onChange={(event) => setSearchState({searchCriteria:event.target.value, resultId:0})}
                                    onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)}>
                             {option.title}
                            </Li>
                        ))}
                </Ul>
            </SuggestContainer>
```

Comment: The grouping. Wikipedia returns `query > pages > pageid > page data` I'm looking to remove the redundant `pageid` to get `query > pages > [set of page data]` or at least parse it into that structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a cue from this question I modified my response by using `Object.values()` like so

```
setOptions({ matches:Object.values(response) })
```